# Where is voter data from the recent General Election?

Tags: data-request, usa, demographics

I'm looking for the rawest form of voter data available from the U.S. Nov 8, 2016 general election.

The source would both let me explore demographic data around voters based on region, correlate that to other items voted on per-ballot, and explain how Google,etc was able to maintain their live analytics of the election during Election Night.

I found a few other questions that referenced formats elections results could be in, but the actual vote data is still evading me.  I expect different states to behave differently / have different interfaces.  And [Open Elections](http://openelections.net/) looks like the best historical record I can find, but where are they pulling their data from?

The related question asking specifically for [demographic data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10059/usa-2016-election-demographic-data) has some sources, but are far too aggregated and historic for my question.

Comment: googles data came from their civic data api...at least some of it

Comment: http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/electionresults.shtml will eventually post this, but hasn't so far.

Comment: related: [county voting data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10085/1511)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many states have posted the data on their election commission websites. The format varies from state to state. To answer your question about [Open Elections](http://openelections.net), they pull their information directly from the state election commission.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these links below, and you can also search "election 2016" in [data.world](https://data.world/) for other related data. There's quite a few users who are already aggregating this data and creating analyses and cool visualizations. If you're interested in collaborating, some are seeking additional contributors to help build out these datasets further. Hope this helps!

[United States General Election 2016 by County](https://data.world/aaronhoffman/us-general-election-2016)
[Quick scrape of the nytime Presidential Election Results.](https://data.world/kidpixo/election-usa-2016-results)