# Individual precinct voting data for Pennsylvania

Tags: usa, government, elections

I'm currently trying to find voting results by precinct for for Pennsylvania. I know several states such as South Carolina have published voting data from the 2016 General Election. This data can be accessed [here](http://www.enr-scvotes.org/SC/64658/182853/en/md.html?cid=20500). Does Pennsylvania, or any other state for that matter, have anything like this?

Comment: I know Ohio has https://vote.ohio.gov/

Comment: http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/electionresults.shtml will eventually list this, but hasn't so far.

Comment: @BarryCarter well this is actually very interesting and it could take a very long time to examine all this data, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find County-level voting data on the election site of [Townhall](http://townhall.com/election/2016/president/).

A kind person has done a scrape of the website and made the data available on Github as a CSV and Ipython notebook.

**[2016 County Election Results](https://github.com/tonmcg/2016_County_Level_Election_Results)**

> Scraping townhall.com for county-level election results from the 2016 presidential general election with Python

[image]

([my source](https://twitter.com/dpatil/status/796902611622436864))

---

The above data source gives a FIPS code for each county. It's sometimes four digit, because the leading 0 is removed when it was converted to an integer, but I think you can map it to the 5 digit codes available from [census.gov](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/cou.html)

```
AL,01,001,Autauga County,H1
AL,01,003,Baldwin County,H1
AL,01,005,Barbour County,H1
AL,01,007,Bibb County,H1
AL,01,009,Blount County,H1
AL,01,011,Bullock County,H1
AL,01,013,Butler County,H1
```

Here's [one 1988 mapping from the CDC](https://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/sci_data/codes/fips/type_txt/cntyxref.asp) between Zip+4 codes and FIPS county codes.

> The County Cross Reference File is a product which provides a
>    relationship between ZIP+4 codes and Federal Information
>    Processing Standard (FIPS) county codes.  The file allows users
>    who have assigned ZIP+4 codes to their address files to obtain
>    county data at the ZIP+4 level.

```
00602000000063000010120PR003AGUADA                   
00602000000063101210240PR003AGUADA                   
00602000000063202410300PR003AGUADA                   
00602000000063303010420PR003AGUADA                   
00602000000063404210538PR003AGUADA
```

(the first 5 digits are the zip code, 00602 is in puerto rico for this example)

Answer (score 3):

[OpenElections](http://openelections.net/) works to acquire and bring to a standard format the precinct level vote results. They do a great job on this as I sift through the Florida results from the 2014 general election. The [Pennsylvania data](http://openelections.net/results/#pa) is available for 2014, but does not appear to have any update for the 2016 primary.

Additionally, you can go to [Voter List Information](http://voterlist.electproject.org/) to find Pennsylvania's website. The Voter List Information

Comment: I'm having a hard time locating that data on Open Elections. I looked for Florida, but could not locate it.

Comment: Please find the link for [Florida](http://openelections.net/results/#fl)